# Delete and add file with a single changelist

Tags: addition, perforce, delete-file, changelist

Is it possible to delete a file and add it again within the same changelist? I want to delete existing images and add new images with the same names.

I've also thought of changing the content of the files, but I'm not sure if that can work for images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems simpler just to open the files for edit and submit the new content. Changing the content works fine for images.